# Bind smallint from database to ajax stars rating in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, rating

I have a simple table which stores reviews along with the rating as below:

```
Create table tblReview
 (
 Id int primary key identity,
 Rating smallint,
 Review nvarchar(max),
 RegistrationId int foreign key references tblAllRegisteredBusiness(RegistrationId),
 ReviewDate DateTime not null Default GetDate()
 )
```

I have a gridview which has an AJAX stars rating control.All i want to do is populate the gridview with all the reviews based on RegistrationId.The gridview is shown as below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="False" Width="618px" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                        <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="auto-style12">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="auto-style58"></td>
                                    <td class="auto-style61">&nbsp;<ajax:Rating ID="rating2" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" StarCssClass="ratingEmpty" WaitingStarCssClass="ratingSaved" EmptyStarCssClass="ratingEmpty" FilledStarCssClass="ratingFilled"></ajax:Rating>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class="auto-style59" style="vertical-align:bottom">&nbsp;<span class="auto-style11">Review by:</span><asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style11"></asp:Label>
                                        <span class="auto-style11">&nbsp;on </span>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" style="font-size: small" Text="<%# Bind('ReviewDate') %>"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="auto-style60"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="auto-style56">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class="auto-style57" colspan="2">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblReview" runat="server" Text="<%# Bind('Review') %>"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="auto-style56">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class="auto-style57" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

I tried to bind the rating as below:

```
 <ajax:Rating ID="rating2" CurrentRating=<%# Rating %>
```

but doesnt work.So i thought of using the rowdatabound event of gridview to bind the rating as below:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IndiaLystConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Rating from tblReview where RegistrationId=@RegistrationId", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationId", lblId.Text);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rdr.Read();
            AjaxControlToolkit.Rating star = (AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)GridView1.FindControl("rate2");
            star.CurrentRating = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Rating"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

which doesnt work again.So what should i do in this case.I thought this would be simple but this is turning out to be one difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this line

```
<ajax:Rating ID="rating2" CurrentRating=<%# Bind('Rating') %>
```

You can also do on the rowdatabound event like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.Rating star = (AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)e.Row.FindControl("rating2");
        star.CurrentRating = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Rating"));

    }
}
```

Comment: it still says ' Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: star.CurrentRating = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Rating"));

Comment: Can you check in the debug mode, what is the value of DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Rating")?

Comment: I am really embarrassed to tell you i don't use the debug mode ever which means i know nothing about it YET.Do you have a tutorial or some good video where i can learn how to test a code using debugger mode and breakpoints?

Comment: Well i just did that and it seems like it is coming out as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work for sure

```
<cc1:Rating ID="rtUserRating" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" 
StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" CurrentRating=**'
<%# Convert.ToInt16(Eval("Rating")) %>

'** EmptyStarCssClass="Star" FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar">
</cc1:Rating>
```

hope you will get reference from above code